# How to make a component draggable but only from a drag icon and not from anywhere else?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a draggable component in which when I drag `<DragIndicatorIcon/>` the whole component will be dragged but when I shouldn't be able to drag the component when the mouse is down on the `div`.

```
import React from 'react'
import DragIndicatorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DragIndicator';

function Drag() {
      return (
            <div draggable style={{ display: 'flex' }} >
                  <DragIndicatorIcon />
                  <div  >Drag me from the icon don't drag me from my text please.</div>
            </div>
      )
}

export default Drag
```

Comment: You can take a look at this `https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd`, it defines a component within which the drag event can take place.

Comment: I know it but I don't wanna use it, It doesn't meet my needs so a build my own and from scratch.... (I need to create sortable TreeView also react-beautiful-dnd code is so long)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import DragIndicatorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DragIndicator';

function Drag() {
      const [Draggable, setDraggable] = useState(false)
      return (
            <div draggable={Draggable} style={{ display: 'flex' }} >
                  <DragIndicatorIcon
                        onMouseDown={e => setDraggable(true)}
                        onmouseUp={e => setDraggable(false)}
                  />
                  <div 
                  onMouseDown={e => setDraggable(false)}
                onmouseUp={e => setDraggable(true)}
                   >Drag me from the icon don't drag me from my text please.</div>
            </div>
      )
}

export default Drag
```